# Generate a table with random numbers

Tags: javascript, performance

I wrote the following code for generating a table with random numbers and would like to ask if there is any way to optimize/enhance/modularize the JavaScript code, especially the addColumn and the addRow functions.

```
<body  onload="initlization()">
<form>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow()" />
<input type="button" class="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow()" />
<input type="button" class="button" value="Add column" onclick="addColumn()" />
<input type="button" class="button" value="delete column" onclick="deleteColumn()" />    
</form>
<table>
<tr>
    <td></td> 
    <td> </td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

This is the JavaScript code:

```
var blocks;
var myTable;
var nums = [];

function initlization() {
  myTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
  shuffle(); //need to shuffle initially 
}

function shuffle() {
  //need to get all tds each time the table is shuffled
  blocks = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  tableSize = blocks.length;
  shuffledArray(0, tableSize);
  for (var i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
    blocks[i].innerHTML = '<span draggable="true">' + nums[i] + '</span>';
  }
}

function addColumn() {
  // Getting current table size by multiplying number of rows by number of   columns
  tableSize = (myTable.rows.length) * (myTable.rows[0].cells.length);
  // Getting new table size by adding the number of rows
  newTableSize = tableSize + (myTable.rows.length);
  shuffledArray(tableSize, newTableSize);
  index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (myTable.rows[0].cells.length) + 1);
  for (var i = 0; i < myTable.rows.length; i++) {
    myCell = myTable.rows[i].insertCell(index);
    myCell.innerHTML = '<span draggable="true">' + nums[i] + '</span>';
  }
}

function addRow() {
  tableSize = (myTable.rows.length) * (myTable.rows[0].cells.length);
  newTableSize = (myTable.rows.length + 1) * (myTable.rows[0].cells.length);
  shuffledArray(tableSize, newTableSize);
  index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (myTable.rows.length) + 1);
  var row = myTable.insertRow(index);
  for (var i = 0; i < myTable.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
    var myCell = row.insertCell(i);
    myCell.innerHTML = '<span draggable="true">' + nums[i] + '</span>';

  }
}

function deleteColumn() {
  var allRows = myTable.rows;
  if (allRows[0].cells.length > 2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < allRows.length; i++) {
      allRows[i].deleteCell(-1);
    }
    shuffle();
  }
}

function deleteRow() {
  if (myTable.rows.length > 2) {
    myTable.deleteRow(0);
    shuffle();
  }
}

function shuffledArray( from,  to) {
for(i=from; i<to;i++){
    nums[i-from]=i;
    }
for (var i = to-from; i; i--) {
    j= Math.floor(Math.random() *i);

    [nums[i - 1], nums[j]] = [nums[j], nums[i - 1]];
    }
}
```

Comment: If [this user](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/120969/nermeen-mattar?tab=profile) is also you then I would recommend mailing the Stack Exchange team to have your accounts merged.